# Best practice for Apache Flink for user defined alerts

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say my Flink job receives a stream of Stock Prices (as an example) and issues alert if lets say a Stock drops below a certain price. Users can add or remove these alert criteria. For example user `abc@somemail.com` creates a rule to be alerted if price of `GME` drops below $100. How can my Flink job dynamically keep track of all these alert criteria in a scalable manner?

I could create an API which my Flink job could call to get all of the updated alert criteria but that would mean calling the API numerous times to keep every thing up to date.

Or I could create a permanent table with Flink Table API, which another Flink job updates as soon as users creates a new alert criteria.

What would be the best practice for this use case?

Notes:

1. Alert should be issued with minimal latency
2. Alert criteria should be updated as soon as user creates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a design sketch for a purely streaming approach:

```java
alertUpdates = alerts
  .keyBy(user)
  .process(managePreviousAlerts)  // uses MapState<Stock, Price>
  .keyBy(stock, price)

priceUpdates = prices
  .keyBy(stock)
  .process(managePriceHistory)
  .keyBy(stock, price)

alertUpdates
  .connect(priceUpdates)
  .process(manageAlertsAndPrices) // uses MapState<User, Boolean>
```

- `managePreviousAlerts` maintains a per-user `MapState` from stocks to alert prices. When a new alert arrives, find the existing alert for this stock (for this user), if any. Then emit two `AlertUpdates`: a `RemoveAlert` event for this (user, stock, oldAlertPrice) and an `AddAlert` event for this (user, stock, newAlertPrice).
- `managePriceHistory` keeps some per-stock pricing history in state, and uses some business logic to decide if the incoming price is a change that merits triggering alerts. (E.g., maybe you only alert if the price went down.)
- `manageAlertsAndPrices` maintains a per-stock, per-price `MapState`, keyed by user.

  - The keys of this `MapState` are all of the users w/ alerts for this stock at this price. Upon receiving a `PriceUpdate`, alert all of these users by iterating over the keys of the `MapState`.
  - Upon receiving a `RemoveAlert`, remove the user from the `MapState`.
  - Upon receiving an `AddAlert`, add the user to `MapState`.

This should scale well. The latency will be governed by the two network shuffles caused by the keyBys.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to `keyBy` price In this case, since price is dynamic and can take on a wide range of values depending on whatever price point used would like to get alerted at, but yeah I get the general idea

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on how do You approach generating alerts in general. My first idea would be to use Kafka to store the new alerts, so that Flink can receive them as a Stream. Then, depending on the requirements You could simply `broadcast` stream of alerts and `connect` it with stream of Stock Prices. This should allow You to scale pretty well.

But if You are using Table API, then using the external Table to store the data may also be a good idea, then You could take a look at something like  [that](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/jdbc.html#lookup-cache).